# Regression loop and store specific coefficient in new dataset (Stata)

Tags: loops, regression, stata, coefficients

I have multiple regression to run in double loop (with ID and year) and then save specific coefficient in new dataset for further analysis. I'm not an advanced user of Stata and I have been unsuccessful to find a way to get the desired dataset. This is what I have done so far (which is very basic)

```
forvalues x=1000/3320 {
    forvalues y=2007/2014 {
        display as text "`x' - `y'"
        regress lnY lnL lnK lnM if (ID==`x' & Year==`y'), vce(robust)
    }
}
```

Next, I want to store ID, Year and coefficient for lnL in new dataset in the following format

```
ID      Year    beta_L
1000    2007    coefficient value
1000    2008    coefficient value
.       .       .
.       .       .
1001    2007    coefficient value
.       .       .
and so on...
```

Sample data that I'm working with

```
ID   Year  lnY       lnL       lnK
1000 2012  5.594402  .6931472  5.493681
1000 2014 11.203094   3.89182  5.173674
1000 2009   9.12585 3.5263605  7.963082
1000 2014  8.042182   2.70805  6.599499
1000 2012  8.260284 2.6390574  5.794077
1000 2013  8.057291 1.0986123  5.455157
1000 2013  6.319292  .6931472  5.746913
1000 2009  8.667063  3.465736  5.716908
1000 2008  6.493629  .6931472   7.79329
1000 2007 9.5332575 3.2580965  6.708956
1000 2013  9.940035 3.5263605  8.670599
1000 2013  5.212381  .6931472  5.404938
1000 2012  5.996401 1.3862944  5.465735
1000 2010  8.229244  2.890372   6.46925
1000 2011 10.998017  3.135494  3.845514
1000 2014  5.207485  1.609438  2.720516
1000 2009   7.75353 1.0986123  2.724515
1000 2012  7.315685 3.4011974  5.967614
1000 2013 11.464064  6.361302 10.841784
1000 2011  7.753608  .6931472  3.232409
1000 2010  8.638702 2.6390574 4.3438053
1000 2012  9.776585  4.744932  8.152783
1000 2007   7.00119  1.609438  5.629177
1000 2009  8.411424   2.70805    6.3282
1000 2011  4.791777  .6931472  3.018835
1000 2009 11.549725  6.516193 10.913407
1000 2010  9.745195 3.9318256   6.40688
1000 2009  9.267692  3.583519  8.845691
1000 2014   8.39663   2.70805  6.152485
1000 2014  9.058921 3.8286414  8.965775
1100 2009  7.899781 2.6390574   8.794945
1100 2007   7.00119 2.1972246   8.033159
1100 2012  5.956254  .6931472   7.295885
1100 2011  2.899934  .6931472   8.412895
1100 2012  7.844419 2.6390574   8.702268
1100 2013  10.08861  3.912023   9.594462
1100 2010  7.868637 2.6390574    8.73182
1100 2013  7.904302 2.6390574  8.6678095
1100 2012 1.7197353  .6931472   8.357231
1100 2012   7.65021  1.609438   6.136364
1100 2010  9.976413    3.7612   9.558953
1100 2014  8.952582 2.6390574   7.544822
1100 2008  9.878766  3.871201   8.280781
1100 2013  8.562812 2.6390574   7.648747
1100 2012  8.616093  2.890372    7.70997
1100 2012  5.730094 1.3862944   6.518791
1100 2014  5.171491  .6931472     5.6845
1100 2011  5.898294  .6931472   2.372208
1100 2008  7.985871  2.833213   8.833616
1100 2009  5.905118  .6931472  3.2353406
1100 2009 3.1379786   1.94591   8.658174
1100 2014  8.041589 2.6390574   8.622295
1100 2013  5.707078 1.0986123   6.481857
1100 2013  7.748852 1.3862944   6.026944
1100 2007  8.270083  2.772589   8.322694
1100 2014  7.742864 1.3862944   6.011713
1100 2011  7.875942  2.564949   8.754793
1100 2010  8.572438  2.890372   8.072155
1100 2010  5.049856 1.7917595   8.547916
1100 2009  9.903218   3.73767   9.558193
1100 2014  6.008263 1.0986123   6.434088
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are hundreds of posts on this kind of problem on Statalist and it's covered explicitly by `statsby`, so your search strategy needs an upgrade.

Your loop commits you to 2321 x 8 regressions, so 18568, and full results displayed, whereas you want just one coefficient from each.

One way to do it more directly is

```
statsby bL=_b[lnL] , by(ID year): ///
regress lnY lnL lnK lnM, vce(robust)
```

Comment: A neat solution as always.

Comment: Thank-you Nick for your solution. I was not having a good day and I should have searched properly rather than posting a duplicate question on the forum.